# Entity Framework, Table per Hierarchy, Discriminator column in type table?

Tags: entity-framework

I'm trying to see if I can have a discriminator column come from another table, not part of the hierarchy.  For example, imagine the following scenario:

- PersonTable (PersonID, PersonTypeID, other fields)
- EmployeeTable (PersonID, etc)
- StudentTable (PersonID, etc)
- PersonTypeTable (PersonTypeID, PersonCategoryCode)

I'm creating an abstract class Person, that is inherited into Student and Employee.

I want to have PersonCategoryCode column be the Discriminator column based on which Student or Employee objects are instantiated by EF.

Is this possible?  Adding PersonTypeTable to PersonTable mapping's yields errors.  PersonTypeID is unfortunately too dynamic to put into static edmx mapping.

Comment: PersonTypeId looks like it could/should be the discriminator, and that only needs 2 fixed values. How can it be "too dynamic" and what does that mean exactly?

Comment: PersonTypes are user defined.  There can be many.  Each has a code however, either it is Student or Employee.  Does that explain the issue better?

Comment: Somewhat, PersonType is not (and cannot be) the basis for the inheritance. You'll have to split that.